# Trying to use "this" to refer to a class's instance variable inside a function within the class's method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object-oriented

Hope that title makes sense.
This is part of an object I have:
The event listener attaches to the correct marker passed in the parameter but inside the function, `this` points to something else.

```
function UserGoogleMap($mapElement) {

    this.$mapElement = $mapElement;
    this.map = {};
    this.marker = null;
    this.coords = new google.maps.LatLng(25.2697, 55.3095) 

    this.initMap = function () {
       google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'dragend', function() {
         console.log(this.marker); // Undefined
         pos = this.marker.getPosition();
         $('#google-map-info').html("Latitude:" + pos.lat() + " Longitude: " +  pos.lng());
       });
    }
```

This works with a local variable:

```
    var marker = this.marker;
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
        pos = marker.getPosition();
        $('#google-map-info').html("Latitude:" + pos.lat() + " Longitude: " +  pos.lng());
    });

this.initMap();

}
```

Is there anyway to rewrite this to use `this.marker?` or am I stuck with creating a local variable to refer to it? Also is there a way to have `this.initMap()` execute automatically instead of having to add `this.initMap();` at the end of the class?

Any other feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing too elegant to be done here, just use

```
var that = this;
```

And inside your functions, use `that`.

As in:

```
function UserGoogleMap($mapElement) {
    this.$mapElement = $mapElement;
    this.map = {};
    this.marker = null;
    this.coords = new google.maps.LatLng(25.2697, 55.3095) 

    var that = this;
    this.initMap = function () {
       google.maps.event.addListener(that.marker, 'dragend', function() {
         console.log(that.marker); // not Undefined anymore! ;-)
         pos = that.marker.getPosition();
         $('#google-map-info').html("Latitude:" + pos.lat() + " Longitude: " +  pos.lng());
       });
    }
}
```

As for the `this.initMap();` part, AFAIK since JavaScript's class concept are not really classes but functions, you'll have to manually call it or really make a construct that'll call it like this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#The_Constructor

Comment: Just realized this after submitting the question.

Comment: Hehe happens all the time, np :-)

Answer (score 3):

The "that" solution works well, but you can also bind your function to this :

```
function UserGoogleMap($mapElement) {
  this.$mapElement = $mapElement;
  this.map = {};
  this.marker = null;
  this.coords = new google.maps.LatLng(25.2697, 55.3095) 

  this.initMap = function () {
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'dragend', function() {
      console.log(this.marker);
      pos = this.marker.getPosition();
      $('#google-map-info').html("Latitude:" + pos.lat() + " Longitude: " +  pos.lng());
    }.bind(this));
  }
}
```

There is a way to execute initMap directly :

```
this.initMap = function () {
  google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'dragend', function() {
    pos = this.marker.getPosition();
      $('#google-map-info').html("Latitude:" + pos.lat() + " Longitude: " +  pos.lng());
    }.bind(this));
    return arguments.callee;
 }();
```

But arguments.callee is deprecated (due to performance issues), so calling initMap manually is better.